# Warning from cryptsetup-initramfs

Tags: debian, initramfs, cryptsetup

Since today I get the following warning when running `update-initramfs -u`:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
```

Previously, I used `cryptsetup-initramfs` to unlock my crypted data partition at boot time. But I removed this and unlock the partition manually now at every reboot (for being able to reboot my home server from remote).

When trying to uninstall `cryptsetup-initramfs`, it wants to deinstall `cryptsetup` also. But I need this for the manual unlock, I strongly assume:

```
me@myserver:~$ sudo apt remove cryptsetup-initramfs
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  cryptsetup cryptsetup-initramfs
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 2 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Nach dieser Operation werden 210 kB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] n
Abbruch.
me@myserver:~$
```

So, what to do? Just ignore the warning? Generally, I don't like warnings that are "normal" ... :D

---

Tried to apply the proposed solution from the answers:

```
me@myserver:~$ LANG=C sudo apt-mark manual cryptsetup
cryptsetup was already set to manually installed.
me@myserver:~$ LANG=C sudo apt remove cryptsetup-initramfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  cryptsetup-run
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cryptsetup cryptsetup-initramfs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 210 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
me@myserver:~$
```

Comment: Always use `LANG=C` when sharing error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian 11 and later, [`cryptsetup` only suggests `cryptsetup-initramfs`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/cryptsetup), so you should be able to remove the latter without removing the former. If you’ve configured `apt` to auto-remove packages which are no longer necessary, you’ll need to indicate that you want to keep `cryptsetup`:

```
sudo apt-mark manual cryptsetup
sudo apt purge cryptsetup-initramfs
```

Since you are running Debian 10, the setup is slighly different. `cryptsetup` is a metapackage which pulls in all the related packages; the actual programs you might want are provided by

- `cryptsetup-bin`: the core `cryptsetup` commands, needed to access encrypted devices
- `cryptsetup-run`: the startup scripts, used to automatically set up devices at boot
- `cryptsetup-initramfs`: the initramfs integration.

You need to decide which of these you want to keep, and mark them as manually installed so that they won’t be removed. Presumably that’s at least

```
sudo apt-mark manual cryptsetup-bin
```

You can then remove the initramfs integration without adverse effects:

```
sudo apt remove cryptsetup-initramfs
```

Answer (score 2):

You apparently have never actually specified that you *want* to have the `cryptsetup` installed; the package manager has installed it to satisfy a dependency of `cryptsetup-initramfs`. As a result, the `cryptsetup` package has been marked "automatically installed", and that means it can be auto-removed if all the packages depending on it are removed.

The solution is to first mark `cryptsetup` as "manually installed", i.e. *installed because you specifically want to have it*.

```
sudo apt-mark manual cryptsetup
```

There are other ways to do this in other `apt` front-ends, like using the <kbd>m</kbd> key in `aptitude`, if you prefer that.

Once `apt` knows you want `cryptsetup` installed, it should no longer suggest removing `cryptsetup` along with `cryptsetup-initramfs`. So you can remove the latter:

```
sudo apt remove cryptsetup-initramfs
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I tried it and it didn't worked (see my update). Is the mentioned `cryptsetup-run` related maybe? This didn't occurred previously or I didn't recognised it..

Comment: `cryptsetup-run` used to exist as a regular package in Debian 10 "Buster".  On the current and previous releases, it should be just a transitional dummy package. Are you running Debian 10 or earlier? If so, that might explain the unexpected behavior: on those old releases, the dependencies used to be arranged differently.

Comment: Yes, this is Debian 10, will have to upgrade soon. Thank you for this hint.